# Certificates are platform-independent, right?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate

I'm about to order a certificate and the order form asks me which server platform (e.g. Apache + mod_ssl) I'm using. It doesn't really matter what I choose, does it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are platform independent but there are different ways of packaging a certificate.  See the certificate file extensions section of this page.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509

You can convert between these formats yourself but SSL providers like to do this for you and provide the format that you need.  Which is why they ask you what your target platform is.  I know with GoDaddy you can download your certificate in any format on the fly once it's been issued.  I'm not sure if the other SSL CA's do it this way though.

Answer (score 0):

They may provide it in a more convenient form for some platforms (thinking Microsoft here) but yeah they are fundamentally platform independent.